# SBT Operations when opening project

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

Is it really necessary that SBT has to execute a lot of operations in the background EACH TIME when I re-open a project in Intellij Idea?

I mean, I do understand that indexing files and stuff like that takes a long time initially, when I create a project. But I don't understand why SBT always takes a minute or so to finish all its operations EACH TIME I re-open the project. What is it doing?

Comment: To be honest with you, I sometimes see this behavior after each _build_ which I do with my project open in IntelliJ.  The bottom line is that there is a huge amount of in-memory state needed for IntelliJ to do all it can do, and it takes time to build up this state.

Comment: So, is it any better with Eclipse instead?

Comment: Great question...I have never used Eclipse extensively.  I would be surprised if it didn't have the same limitations though.  Someone else will comment/answer I'm sure.

Comment: Do you mean SBT in Intellij? Or you are running Intellij in parallel with standalone SBT in command line?